The dual $C^*$ algebra of unitization
Let $A$ be a $C^*$ algebra and $\rho:A\to B(H)$ a representation. We define the dual $C^*$-algebra $D_\rho(A)$ as $\{T\in B(H): [T,\rho(a)]\in K(H) \text{ for all } a\in A \}$. We are interested when $\rho$ is an ample representation, see here.
Suppose $A$ is non-unital, and amply represented by $\rho$. We can extend $\rho$ to an ample representation $\tilde{\rho}$ on the unitization $\tilde{A}$ using
$$
(a,\lambda)\mapsto \begin{bmatrix} \rho(a)+\lambda 1_H & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda 1_H\end{bmatrix}
$$
In the book Analytic K-homology by Higson and Roe, on pp 128, the authors tried to construct $\tilde{\rho}$ but did not spell out the detail. The above is how I think of it.
Then the authors said that $D_{\tilde{\rho}}(\tilde{A})$ take the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix} D_\rho(A) & K(H) \\ K(H) & B(H)\end{bmatrix}
$$
However, it is not clear to me why the off-diagonal must be compact. Let $T\in D_{\tilde{\rho}}(\tilde{A})$, then
$$
\begin{bmatrix} T_{11} & T_{12} \\ T_{21} & T_{22}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \rho(a)+\lambda 1_H & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda 1_H\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} \rho(a)+\lambda 1_H & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda 1_H\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} T_{11} & T_{12} \\ T_{21} & T_{22}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} [T_{11},\rho(a)] & -\rho(a)T_{12} \\ T_{21}\rho(a) & 0\end{bmatrix}
$$
is compact. Thus $T_{11}\in D_\rho(A)$ and $T_{22}$ can be anything. However, according to this, we cannot conclude that $T_{12},T_{21}$ are compact. I was wondering if the $\tilde{\rho}$ I constructed is not correct.

A small correction: the upper right corner of the commutator should be $-\rho(a)T_{12}$ instead of $\rho(a)T_{12}$.

But yeah, assuming your $\tilde{\rho}$ is correct, then the result is just false, and my counterexample to your last question serves as a counterexample here as well. But I wouldn’t know if it’s an error of the authors or if you have misunderstood what $\tilde{\rho}$ is. (Though your definition of $\tilde{\rho}$ seems the most natural choice to me.)

@DavidGao I have doubt about whether the examples you gave are non-degenerate. Could you elaborate there? Thanks.

I’m not sure what exactly to elaborate on? It’s just a special case of my answer to your first question on constructing ample representations. Do you want me to elaborate on that question?

Yes please. I have added a comment there.

Interesting... The later development in the book seems to depend on this observation. I will have to find a $\tilde{\rho}$ that works.

I’ve checked the book you cited and I don’t see any other way to interpret what $\tilde{\rho}$ is. It seems to me this is an error the authors made.

@DavidGao I am being stupid!! In the paragraph, the authors assumed $A$ to be unital! Thus $\rho$ must be unital as well. Thanks for checking.

Oh, yeah, I missed that as well. I suppose that solves the issue.
